# Can I access the game variable used in Program.cs? (MonoGame)

Tags: c#, variables, local, monogame

I am making a game using MonoGame and C#. The main class is called Program.cs and is automatically added when creating the project. It uses these lines of code to run the game:

```
using (var game = new Game1())
    game.Run();
```

The Game1 class contains properties that I need to use in other classes, but the only way to access them at the moment is by making the properties static and using code like the following:

```
int exampleNumber = Game1.MyNumberProperty;
```

I'm sure that this is bad programming practice, so I was wondering if there was any way for me to access the "game" instance variable from Program.cs so that I don't need to use static properties. However, the "game" instance is a local variable. Is there any way at all for me to call it using a manner like the following:

```
int exampleNumber = Program.game.MyNumberProperty;
```

Edit:

I've created an example class to hold some of the variables and have instantiated it in the Game1 constructor.

```
MyClass exampleClass;

public Game1() : base()
{
    graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
    Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

    exampleClass = new MyClass(); //The class is instantiated here
}
```

However, I am confused as to how I can now access this instance in another class. The way that I am doing it now is to make the instance static and use a static property, but now I'm back to the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

Put your variables inside specific classes, something that describes them better than just game. For example, a Settings class, this way you would actually ask for the Settings object that is stored in the game class, it gives more context to what your dependencies are.

Now, to fix the static property you would have to create for the Settings class, you have 2 ways:

1: Instantiate all objects manually in the start up of the game class, basically you will wire all the dependencies yourself.

2: Use a dependency injection framework like Unity.